# Synonymize [wtp] and [wtp-eclipse]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[wtp](/questions/tagged/wtp) contains 114 questions.
Tag wiki:

> The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) project extends the Eclipse
>   platform with tools for developing Web and Java EE applications. It
>   includes source and graphical editors for a variety of languages,
>   wizards and built-in applications to simplify development, and tools
>   and APIs to support deploying, running, and testing apps.

[eclipse-wtp](/questions/tagged/eclipse-wtp) contains 73 questions.

Tag wiki:

> The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) project extends the Eclipse
>   platform with tools for developing Web and Java EE applications.

Those 2 could be made synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed: [wtp](/questions/tagged/wtp) --> [eclipse-wtp](/questions/tagged/eclipse-wtp)